# How to have a responsive twitter Bootstrap layout with fixed width nav bars on each side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a layout design where there are fixed width nav bars on each side with a fluid center layout.  I am also looking to see if I can make it responsive.  The nav bars should collapse into buttons which make the navbars slideout such as this is example:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

which is nearly what I need, but the nav bars are not fixed in the example.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What's the question??

Answer (score 0):

This example on Bootply may help you. It has left and right sidebars that toggle off-canvas on smaller screen widths..

### http://bootply.com/108332